# Issues pulling value from file and using it in calculation

Tags: python

My friend's having issues with this code!

```
file = open('attributes.txt', 'r')
Name = file.readline()
Name = Name[1:]
Name = Name[:-2]
print(Name)
Strength = file.readline()
Strength = Strength[-3:-1]
print(Strength)
Skill = file.readline()
Skill = Skill[-3:-1]
print(Skill)
Name2 = file.readline()
Name2 = Name2[1:]
Name2 = Name2[:-2]
print(Name2)
Strength2 = file.readline()
Strength2 = Strength2[-3:-1]
print(Strength2)
Skill2 = file.readline()
Skill2 = Skill2[-3:-1]
print(Skill2)

Strengthmod = int((Strength) - (Strength2))
if Strengthmod < 0:
    Strengthmod = 0
    print("Character dies")
print(Strengthmod)
```

We get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:/Computing/Course Work/A453 - Python/Task Three", line 23, in <module>
    Strengthmod = int((Strength) - (Strength2))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

Tried changing the variables to int( and all kinds of things but to no luck, any comments or help would be appreciated!

Comment: You want `int(Strength) - int(Strength2)`. You have to convert the data to numbers before you can do calculations.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for a full explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Tip: Do not use uppercase characters to name your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Strengthmod = int(Strength) - int(Strength2)
```

The problem with the line that you had was that you were trying to subtract one string from another which (as the error message said) isn't supported.

Comment: @Bonifacio2 no problem, now we can delete these comments and keep the answer clean.